# Re-ordering axis in ggplot2 error - ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

As a gift I am working on a beer report for an avid beer drinker I know. I am trying to plot the number of beer on a given day of the week. The data I am working with has one row for each individual beer and one of the columns is the day of the week that it was drank. When I use the following command I get essentially what I would like:

```
ggplot(data = raw_data_categories_added_days_added) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Day), color = "black", fill = "blue")
```

The issue I am having is that this produces a plot with the x axis in alphabetical order, I would rather Monday Tuesday Wednesday and so on.

I have tried re-ordering by:

```
raw_data_ordered_by_day <- factor(raw_data_categories_added_days_added, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

But then when I go to re-plot with the new ordered data with:

```
ggplot(data = raw_data_ordered_by_day) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Day), color = "black", fill = "blue")
```

I get the following error:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

I have looked through other similar questions and those solutions are not working. Please help Thank you!

Comment: try `raw_data_categories_added_days_added$Day <- factor(raw_data_categories_added_days_added$Day, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))`

Comment: thank you! 

I had come across this before and tried it, but got an error again because I was trying to keep things separate and renamed the output. Didn't rename the output this time as in your answer, got no error, then it plotted in the order I wanted. Again thanks! Saved me a lot of time